# Python Selenium, checking if element is present. and if it was present I want it to return a boolean value of TRUE

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Python Selenium, checking if element is present. and if it was present I want it to return a boolean value of TRUE

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<td data-id="329083" data-property="status" xe-field="status" class="readonly" data-content="Status" style="width: 8%; display: none;" title=" FULL: 0 of 20 seats remain."><div class="status-full"> <span class="status-bold ">FULL</span>: 0 of 20 seats remain.</div></td>
```

I need to check whenever the title changes to " 1 of 20 seats remain." and return a boolean value of TRUE

idk if this helps but this code for checking if someone drops the course from my univercity, i'll create a loop that will keep refreshing the page until someone drops a course so i can register.

Sorry if my english is bad

Thanks in advance

I tried these two different methods to check if the title changed:

1st code:

```
status = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/main/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[11]").text
status.get_attribute(" FULL: 0 of 20 seats remain.")
if status == "FULL:0of20seatsremain.":
    print("Seats Not Avaliable")
else:
    print("Error")
```

2nd Code:

```
title = " FULL: 0 of 20 seats remain."
courseStat = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR("[title^='" + title + "']")).text
```

Output for 1st Code:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'str' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
    status.get_attribute(" FULL: 0 of 20 seats remain.")
```

Output for 2st Code:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'str' object is not callable
    courseStat = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR("[title^='" + title + "']")).text
```

I can't share the link because it's the portal for our university, which u will have to log in to view the page source or inspect elements, Here is a screenshot of the HTML code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI5Gq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element attribute containing desired data is `title`.
So, the first code can be fixed as following:

```py
status = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/main/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[11]").text
status.get_attribute("title")
if "FULL" in status:
    print("No seats available")
else:
    print("Available seat found")
```

While you have to improve the locator there.
To correct the second approach we need to see that web page to define a correct locator for that element.

Comment: I can't share the link because it's the portal for our university, which u will have to log in to view the page source or inspect elements, I added an image to HTML code above, thanks for the reply :) @Prophet

Comment: The HTML of a single element is not enough, but I hope the first approach will be enough.

Comment: It did work it printed "No seats available", thank you :) @Prophet

Comment: Great. It so the issue is resolved :)